# Parsing double quotes from xml

Tags: android

I have xml file in server. I am parsing this xml using DOM(xml is not big). In one node there is string with double quotes.

```
<NODE1>hello "world"</NODE1>
```

When i see this xml url in browser and check its source it looks like this:

```
<NODE1>hello &quot;world&quot;</NODE1>
```

So when i parse this value i get string till double quotes. It seems after double quotes parser doesn't go forward. Any help ? I want to use DOM only in my current situation. This xml is used by other platform also apart from android. Like in iPhone its working perfectly. What should I do to read all value in android using DOM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but have a look at using CDATA
http://www.globalguideline.com/xml/XML_CDATA.php

Comment: Putting string with special characters inside CDATA works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A xml that contains double quote in a value is not valid according to specification: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14068. I would suggest that you escape the special characters server side otherwise you will not be able to parse the xml.